# Is it correct to use the phrase "pay attention" with "that"?

Tags: grammar, to-for, this-that

Is it correct to say "Pay attention that..."? or must I use "Pay attention to..."

For example: "An attention should be paid that this is a one-way street".

Comment: The *that* is fine. The *an* is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. Why the "an" is wrong?

Comment: Because you pay attention. Uncountable. Not one attention or seven attentions. You yourself used the construction correctly, thrice, before suddenly throwing in an article for reasons unspecified.

Answer (score 6):

Whilst it is difficult to fault 'Attention should be paid that this is a one-way street' as being ungrammatical, it would nonetheless be an unusual, and slightly clumsy way of putting it.

If it were me I would say one of the following depending on whether I was speaking, writing, putting up a notice etc:

'Please pay attention to this being a one-way street.'

'Please pay attention to the fact that this is a one way street.'

'Please pay attention. This is a one-way street'

'One way street. Please pay attention'.

'Attention please; this is a one-way street.'

'Please note that this is a one-way street'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would you suggest in case of writing an article, when I want from the reader to pay attention to something that was described before. For example: "Attention should paid that X is defined...." I prefer not to use the direct approach of: "Pay attention". Thanks again.

Comment: Well you could say 'Please pay attention to the note on page 46'. But I am wondering if you are using the most appropriate verb here. 'Pay attention' is quite a strong and instructive expression. Can you not say simply 'for description of this, see page 27'.

Comment: @YuriFeigin in that context, the most common form is "_Note that_ if X is not defined, bad things happen".

Answer (score 3):

You're using "pay attention" 2 different ways and I think that is muddying the waters a bit.

In transitive use you pay attention **to** something.

However there is also the intransitive use:

> "Pay attention!"

So your second example (with the "an" removed, as @RegDwight noted)

> "Attention should be paid that this is a one-way street".

Can also be stated:

> "Attention should be paid. This is a one-way street".

In this case "attention" is not directly tied to "that". "That" is being used as a conjunction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would you suggest in case of writing an article, when I want from the reader to pay attention to something that was described before. For example: "Attention should paid that X is defined...." I prefer not to use the direct approach of: "Pay attention". Thanks again.

Comment: "The passive voice should be avoided" ;) You would have to say "attention should be paid that x is defined..." when it's much simpler and more direct to say something like "Note that x is defined" or "Ensure that x is defined" if the user is expected to define x.