# Is it gramatically ok to say "pay me attention"?

Tags: grammar, questions

I have recently debated with my English teacher if its ok to say:

"Stop playing and pay me attention!"

Any insight will be very much appreciated.

Comment: *Pay attention to* and *take care of* are a few of the most commonly used phrasal verbs in English. You don't want to change the order there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is grammatically correct, and will be understood.

However, the more common formulation is "*pay attention to me*".

"*Pay me attention*" sounds quite odd, but it is understandable.

Comment: Many ungrammatical sentences are understandable. The "odd" feeling you mention is ungrammaticality. _Pay attention to_ is a fixed idiomatic phrase, and its object (_me_) is not an indirect object and therefore does not participate in Dative-Movement (_give the book to her ~ give her the book_); instead, it is really a direct object (of the phrase "pay attention to"), and may be passivized: _She was paid attention to for a while, but now no one believes her_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Thanks; I stand corrected. OP: You accepted my answer, but please understand that I was mistaken in saying that the sentence is grammatically correct: it apparently is not.

Comment: Contrast _give me your attention_, where there is no idiom involved, and _me_ is the indirect object.

Comment: more common even, than "Pay attention to me" would be simply "Pay attention!" Seing as you're the one talking, there is no need to call attention to the object. It will be implied.
"Stop playing, and pay attention!"

Comment: @Colin: _Attention_ is not physical, and is not passing from source to goal, so actually _give attention_  is metaphorical. Practically anything dealing with human minds, thoughts, or emotions is metaphoric, because we don't experience them objectively and jointly, like we do physical reality.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I didn't say anything about metaphor. I said _give attention_ is not an idiom.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Not sure anything is experienced objectively.....but in instructions to students, this is moot. These sentences are imperative and therefore do not require an object. Shut up and pay attention! No need for to me.

Comment: @JohnLawler That doesn’t seem quite right to me. _Attention_ just needs a determiner/modifier for the indirect(?) object to undergo dative movement (“We didn’t pay any attention to him / We didn’t pay him any attention”), which reoccurs in other double object constructions as well. (All the examples I can think of are with _pay/afford/grant/bestow_ type… coincidence?)

Answer (score 2):

"[Stop Playing and] Pay Attention [,please]" is the most acceptable (in British English)

"Pay Attention" is standard usage for "Pay Attention To Me": the object pronoun is not needed in self referral; in fact, its an annoying extra.

However, in non self referral then it is necessary to state the object clearly, as in "Pay Attention To The Road" [to an easily-distracted driver].

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to me (please).

Pay me your attention. Pay me a little attention.

[Is it correct to use the phrase "pay attention" with "that"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152441/is-it-correct-to-use-the-phrase-pay-attention-with-that)